# Set the file path to Resources folder in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#

I am developing with VS2005 and I need to add an image to my tree view node.The image is located in the project in Resources folder. The following code is working fine and the image is displayed as expected.

```
ImageList myImageList = new ImageList(); 
myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"E:\MyProject\HRProject\Attendence_Module\Attendence_Module\Resources\Employees.jpeg"));
```

Is there any way to give the path for the resource folder/file directly without mapping the complete path? If I can will I be able to deploy the project with the same path in another computer?

I have added the image through the properties and then to resources and tried below code.

```
myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Properties.Resources.Employees));
```

But it generate two exceptions

```
1)The best overloaded method match for System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(string)' has some invalid arguments    

2)Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `myImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.Employees);`

Comment: I tried but it generates me two exceptions as described above

Comment: In your example above you're calling Image.FromFile(...) - you need to omit that and add it to your list directly as in my answer

Comment: I ll send u a fruit basket  :)   yours works with me fine .. TanQ

Answer (score 1):

First, did you set the image as an "Embedded Ressource" (Right-click your image => Properties...)

Second, try loading your image like this :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = 
    thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("Attendence_Module.Employees.jpg");
myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(file));
```

Comment: It compiles fine but in run time  errors as

   System.ArgumentException: Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)

Comment: I think @auburg's answer is right, you should just remove the `Image.FromFile` in your code as he pointed out.

Comment: Of coz.... by the way can you detail your answer as well... thinks it also helpful to me

Comment: What do you mean by "detail my answer"?

Comment: Did you add the image to assemblies ?